# Derivatives API Java Client Role Enums

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

We have recently updated to the latest forge-api-java-client jar.

There are currently issues when calling `/modelderivative/v2/designdata/{urn}/metadata` during a PDF upload.

As the request object cannot be mapped into the Manifest response due to errors with unknown enums being returned for ManifestChildren.RoleEnum
`Manifest -> ManifestDerivative -> ManifestChildren -> RoleEnum`

I have been able to work around this issue by adding the four missing enums (leaflet, leaflet-zip, pdf-strings, pdf-page) to the jar and building it locally.

I have searched and cannot find any release notes around these new enums/response objects, and was wondering if I could get pointed in the right location for these changes so I can keep an eye on future updates.
Also I would like to confirm that there are not other changes in the recent updates that may affect other Manifest responses we have not yet seen.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for bringing that up. The leaflet/pdf roles have been around for a while but I don't see them documented anywhere, either. I'll talk to the Model Derivative team and make sure that the roles are documented.

As for the Java SDK, please submit a Github issue or a pull request to https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-java-client and we'll take a look at it.

Comment: I have raised the ticket as an issue on Github, however there appears to be a few older open issues, is there anyone I could contact to try get this prioritised?

Comment: Feel free to contact us via `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com` to bump the priority of the request.